# Vue test utils not recognising $http in the tests

Tags: vue.js, axios, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Have a Vue app with axios setup and is using it as `this.$http.get` in the components and that is working fine.

In running the specs using Jest I get an error: `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

I know I can mock axios with maxios. How do I get Jest to recognise $http so it does not throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a local instance of Vue for your tests, to which you introduce the Vue Plugins you are using, such as axios.

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils"
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'


const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

and later, in your actual tests:

```
it('should mount the component where I want to use $http', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyApiComponent, { localVue });
    ... do stuff to wrapper here ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Georg. I have done as above. Unfortunately I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` when running the test